# Fold C Preprocessor in VIM

Tags: vim, folding

Is it possible to fold C preprocessor in VIM. For example:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
  //some block of code
  myfunction();
#endif
```

I want to fold it so that it becomes:

```
 +--  4 lines: #if defined(DEBUG)---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial due to the limitations of Vim's highlighting engine: it cannot highlight overlapping regions very well.  You have two options as I see it:

1. Use syntax highlighting and much about with the `contains=` option until it works for you (will depend on some plugins probably):

   ```
   syn region cMyFold start="#if" end="#end" transparent fold contains=ALL
   " OR
   syn region cMyFold start="#if" end="#end" transparent fold contains=ALLBUT,cCppSkip
   " OR something else along those lines
   " Use syntax folding
   set foldmethod=syntax
   ```

   This will probably take a lot of messing around and you may never get it working satisfactorily.  Put this in `vimfiles/after/syntax/c.vim` or `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.
2. Use fold markers.  This will work, but you won't be able to fold on braces or anything else that you might like.  Put this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` (or the equivalent vimfiles path on Windows):

   ```
   " This function customises what is displayed on the folded line:
   set foldtext=MyFoldText()
   function! MyFoldText()
       let line = getline(v:foldstart)
       let linecount = v:foldend + 1 - v:foldstart
       let plural = ""
       if linecount != 1
           let plural = "s"
       endif
       let foldtext = printf(" +%s %d line%s: %s", v:folddashes, linecount, plural, line)
       return foldtext
   endfunction
   " This is the line that works the magic
   set foldmarker=#if,#endif
   set foldmethod=marker
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get it working to my liking by adding these lines to my c.vim syntax file:

```
syn match   cPreConditMatch display "^\s*\zs\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|endif\)\>"

+syn region cCppIfAnyWrapper  start="^\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\|ifdef\|ifndef\|elif\)\s\+.*\s*\($\|//\|/\*\|&\)" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" contains=TOP,cCppInIfAny,cCppInElseAny fold
+syn region cCppInIfAny  start="^\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\|ifdef\|ifndef\|elif\)\s\+.*\s*\($\|//\|/\*\|&\)" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\s*\|elif\s\+\|endif\)\>"me=s-1 containedin=cCppIfAnyWrapper contains=TOP
+syn region cCppInElseAny  start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|elif\)" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>"me=s-1 containedin=cCppIfAnyWrapper contains=TOP

if !exists("c_no_if0")
```